# Pathfiding problems in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation, artificial-intelligence

I and my friend have a problem with pathfinding in Unity. We made an enemies on scene, NavMesh and script but this units all the time get bugged and went to the edge of NavMesh and stucked here. We tried many options but we dont know how to fix it. There are our scripts and some screenshoots:

```
    Transform target;
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    void Start()
    {
        target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        FaceTarget();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);
        agent.SetDestination(target.position);
        FaceTarget();
    }
    void FaceTarget()
    {
        Vector3 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
       Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
    }
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it behave differently if you copy this line `target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;` directly to the top of the Update() function?

Comment: Nothing change :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `agent.destination = target.position` in the `Update()` function.